# Change order status string from "Completed" to "Shipped"

Tags: 7, commerce

I'd like to change the order status string from "Completed" to "Shipped" to allow for better communication between us and the customer.

[Commerce Custom Order Status](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_order_status) would sidestep this problem by allowing me to create a new status, but that isn't the best way around it, because there might be triggers set for "completed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing for you to do would be to alter the order status info array to give the "Completed" status a new title. The example in the documentation actually demonstrates specifically how to change the title of the completed status. Look for hook_commerce_order_status_info_alter() in commerce_order.api.php.

There are ways to override strings through the user interface, but this is such a small module change that I'd really recommend directly making it in a site-specific module.

Comment: thanks! used `hook_commerce_order_status_info_alter(&$order_statuses) {
  $order_statuses['completed']['title'] = t('Shipped');
}
` It worked for the user viewing in their order history, but it still shows "completed" in the admin pages (admin/commerce/orders/list). Is there away to change the name for the admin pages too, because the person who administers that might get confused

Comment: **Ryan** answer @ashash question please, is there any way to change in admin pages too?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a new order status instead of modifying the "Completed" order status, since that usually means the order is done-done-done.  Something like "Pending: Shipping" (in the "Pending" order state) would make more sense given a workflow like this:

- Pending: Pending -- The order is paid and ready for shipping.
- Pending: Shipping* -- The order has shipped and may have a tracking number attached. *Note: You would need to add this status value in a custom module.
- Completed: Completed -- The order was delivered, shipping has been fulfilled, no further action required by the store.

See also:

- https://drupalcommerce.org/faq/order-states
- http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/order-info-hooks

You can certainly add to the "Pending" state as suggested above for something simple.  For a more detailed example, you can also have a separate "Shipping" state and statuses:

```php
/**
 * Shipping status
 */
define('SHIPPING_PENDING', 'shipping_pending');
define('SHIPPING_SHIPPED', 'shipping_shipped');
define('SHIPPING_DELAYED', 'shipping_delayed');
define('SHIPPING_CANCELED', 'shipping_canceled');
define('SHIPPING_DELIVERED', 'shipping_delivered');

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_order_state_info()
 */
function example_commerce_order_state_info() {
  $order_states = array();

  $order_states['shipping'] = array(
    'name' => 'shipping',
    'title' => t('Shipping'),
    'description' => t('Orders in the shipping process.'),
    'weight' => 10,
    'default_status' => SHIPPING_PENDING,
  );

  return $order_states;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_order_status_info()
 */
function example_commerce_order_status_info() {
  $order_statuses = array();

  $order_statuses[SHIPPING_PENDING] = array(
    'name' => SHIPPING_PENDING,
    'title' => t('Shipping: Pending'),
    'state' => 'shipping',
    'weight' => 1,
  );
  $order_statuses[SHIPPING_SHIPPED] = array(
    'name' => SHIPPING_SHIPPED,
    'title' => t('Shipping: Shipped'),
    'state' => 'shipping',
    'weight' => 2,
  );
  $order_statuses[SHIPPING_DELAYED] = array(
    'name' => SHIPPING_DELAYED,
    'title' => t('Shipping: Delayed'),
    'state' => 'shipping',
    'weight' => 3,
  );
  $order_statuses[SHIPPING_CANCELED] = array(
    'name' => SHIPPING_CANCELED,
    'title' => t('Shipping: Canceled'),
    'state' => 'shipping',
    'weight' => 4,
  );
  $order_statuses[SHIPPING_DELIVERED] = array(
    'name' => SHIPPING_DELIVERED,
    'title' => t('Shipping: Delivered'),
    'state' => 'shipping',
    'weight' => 5,
  );

  return $order_statuses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drupalcommerce complete hook to change the $order status:

```
function hook_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
  // insert code
}
```

Comment: The questioner doesn't just want to use a different status but actually wants to rename an existing one.