# How to edit default Commerce Order status?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am trying to edit the label of a **default** Commerce Order status (Pending:pending).

I have tried through `commerce_order.api.php` like it is explained in this post: [Change order status string from "Completed" to "Shipped"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118385/change-order-status-string-from-completed-to-shipped) and [on this page](https://drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/order-info-hooks#order-status) but unfortunately it did not work for me. More, in this PHP file, the Completed status should display Finished and it doesn't work either??

The [Commerce custom Order Status](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_order_status) works fine with new statuses but I did not find any way to edit default ones.

Thanks for any tip.

Comment: Solution in this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118385/change-order-status-string-from-completed-to-shipped works for me. Kindly paste your code for changing Label.

Comment: Considering your success with the related post, I guess my code is wrong, I am currently working on it, I'll be back. Thanks

Comment: A "noob" mistake made my custom module wrong. Everything is fine and works with Ryan's solution in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118385/change-order-status-string-from-completed-to-shipped

Comment: I think you should rework your last comment into an actual answer from your self (and mark it as accepted). That way this question will no longer be shown as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan's solution in [Change order status string from "Completed" to "Shipped"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118385/change-order-status-string-from-completed-to-shipped) works finally, my code was wrong.

So, for anyone having the same need, create a mini-custom module using the function hook_commerce_order_status_info_alter (dependencies commerce_order) and paste your new label like it is done for Completed status.

You may find the exact status machine names (e.g. "pending") in commerce_order.module.